# SQL Server: split a column value into two separate columns based on another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Access`:

```
logId   empid   empname  inout   tim  
----------------------------------------------------    
230361   0100     XYZ     0      2015-08-01 10:00:03
230362   0106     XYZ     0      2015-08-01 10:30:00
230363   0100     XYZ     1      2015-08-01 12:00:00
```

which records each employee's in time and out time. `inout=0` means in and `inout=1` means out

I would like to create a table as below from this table

```
empid  empname     timIn                 timOut
-------------------------------------------------------------    
0100     XYZ       2015-08-01 10:00:03   2015-08-01 12:00:00
0106     XYZ       2015-08-01 10:30:00
```

First I tried case as follows:

```
select 
    empid, empname, inout,
    case when inout = 0 then tim end as 'timIn',
    case when inout = 1 then tim end as 'timout'
```

But NULLs were a problem the result was

```
0100  xyz       2015-08-01 10:00:03   NULL
0100  xyz       NULL                  2015-08-01 12:00:00
```

Second I tried `PIVOT`, but the problem was I had to use an aggregate function. I need all in-out times and cannot take an aggregate of that.

Is there any alternative way to get the desired result?

Comment: If the date was a separate column you could join the table to itself using `empname`, `date` as keys, with the left table having `inout=0` and the right table `inout=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), in conjunction with `TOP 1` and the correct `ORDER BY` to get the next out event after each in event

```
SELECT  i.empID,
        i.empname,
        TimeIn = i.tim,
        TimeOut = o.tim
FROM    Access AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 tim
            FROM    Access AS o
            WHERE   o.EmpID = i.EmpID
            AND     o.InOut = 1
            AND     o.tim > i.tim
            ORDER BY o.Tim
        ) AS o
WHERE   i.InOut = 0;
```

So you are simply selecting all `in` events (table aliased `i`), then for each `in` event, finding the next `out` event, if there is not one, then the time out field will be null.

---

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @Access TABLE (LogID INT NOT NULL, EmpID CHAR(4) NOT NULL, empname VARCHAR(50), InOut BIT NOT NULL, tim DATETIME2 NOT NULL);
INSERT @Access (LogID, EmpID, empname, InOut, tim)
VALUES
    (230361, '0100', 'XYZ', 0, '2015-08-01 10:00:03'),
    (230362, '0106', 'XYZ', 0, '2015-08-01 10:30:00'),
    (230363, '0100', 'XYZ', 1, '2015-08-01 12:00:00');

SELECT  i.empID,
        i.empname,
        TimeIn = i.tim,
        TimeOut = o.tim
FROM    @Access AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 tim
            FROM    @Access AS o
            WHERE   o.EmpID = i.EmpID
            AND     o.InOut = 1
            AND     o.tim > i.tim
            ORDER BY o.Tim
        ) AS o
WHERE   i.InOut = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

**update:** Based on comment that I should improve this query to take all dates data and not just last date's data, updated query simply includes a new date column

```
select empid,empname,d,[0] as [timin],[1] as [timOut]
from
(select empid,empname, cast(tim as DATE)as d,inout,tim from tbl) s
pivot
(max(tim) for inout in ([0],[1]))p
```

updated fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1bc7/1

> try `PIVOT` query like this:
>
> ```
> select empid,empname,[0] as [timin],[1] as [timOut]
> from
> (select empid,empname,inout,tim from tbl) s
> pivot
> (max(tim) for inout in ([0],[1]))p
> ```
>
> added SQL fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c3bf/1

Comment: This would return valid values only for the last date per employee

Comment: Thank you @DhruvJoshi-especially for the fiddle. I will check and get back to you

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Thanks but GarethD's solution is more clean. Thank you again for the support!

Answer (score 1):

So what I think you want to do is find the first time out after each time in. The following SQL should do that.

```
Select 
empid,
empname,
tim as timein 
(select top 1 tim 
 from my_table outTimes 
 where outTimes.inout = 1 and 
       outTimes.empid = inTimes.empid and 
       outTimes.tim > inTimes.tim 
 orderby outTimes.tim asc
) as timeout
from my_table inTimes
when inout=0
```

The critical bit here is the orderby asc and the top 1.  This is what gives you the next time in the table.

Comment: timeout is a sqlserver keyword